# Using lytebox and trying to prevent scrolling in the background page

Tags: javascript, jquery, lytebox

When I have a page load into the popup lytebox window, I want only the window contents to be scrollable and NOT the page behind (so that you don't click off and then lose your place).

I've tried a few things using variations of

```
document.body.style.className = "noscroll";
```

Here is the css I used that I added:

```
.noscroll { position: fixed; overflow-y:hidden }
.yesscroll { position: static; overflow-y:auto }
```

I've also tried this using just "overflow".  No luck either.

I tried using an "onClick" and I also used Lytebox's own Event Callbacks to call a script to set the new class onLoad with BeforeStart and onunload with AfterEnd.

But nothing is working—not even when I put an alert() in the code to check if it's being called at all.  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: When the lytebox opens, set body to overflow hidden and reset it on lytebox closing

Comment: I have done that.  Sorry I didn't explain better.  I'll add more in the Edit